# How to find out how many applications is installed in my ios device from ios app

Tags: ios

can i find out the list of All Application which is installed in my ios device. With the help of ios sdk. or any application or code  which will give me the result for that.

please give me suggestion.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I know the way but that was using Private APIs, if u use that way then you will not be able to put your app on App Store. If you still want then let me know

Comment: @MehulThakkar please can you explain about private api for  Finding list of installed apps on iphone then please suggest

Comment: NSArray *allBundles = [[objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") sharedInstance] allApplications];

Comment: from above command, you will get array of all SBApplications installed in your device, now you can get information of any Application by calling method of SBApplication(search private headers of in github), for ex. SBApplication *app=[allBundles objectAtIndex:2]; [app bundleIndentifier] will give it bundleId, [app displayIdentifier] will give appName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the application list and name that user had installed using this code...

```
static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";

    NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];

    NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];

    cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

    user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"];
```

i tested in ios6 it's working fine